# REST Postman How to use datafiles in Runner for more then one endpoint

Tags: rest, automation, postman, data-driven-tests, runner

I like to use the Runner in Postman to run / test a whole collection of endpoints. Each endpoint should get different parameter or request body data on each iteration.

So far i figured out the data file usage for one endpoint. See https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/working-with-data-files/

But is there a way to provide data for more then one endpoint where the endpoints need different variables in the same run?

example:

[GET]categories/:categoryId?lang=en

[GET]articles/?filter[height]=10,40&sort[name]=desc

Datafile for first endpoint:

```
[{
   "categoryId": 1123,
   "lang": en
},
{
   "categoryId": 3342,
   "lang": de
}]
```

Datafile for second endpoint:

```
[{
   "filter": "height",
   "filterValue": "10,40",
   "sort": "name",
   "sortDir": "desc"
},
{
   "filter": "material",
   "filterValue": "chrome",
   "sort": "relevance",
   "sortDir": "asc"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, there is no way to add more data files. https://community.postman.com/t/pass-multiple-data-files-to-a-collection/899

My suggestion is

1. Separate each endpoint that need data file into different collections.
2. Use `newman` as library to run it all.

Comment: Separating the endpoints into different collections is not a viable way for us. So we will look into external testing tools.